# Aggregate many generics in one record

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am defining types for a complex javascript module.
There is a function that handles many types which are passed by generics (for example):

```
export interface ModelState<
    // FetchList
    FetchListPayload,
    FetchListResponse,
    FetchListError,
    // FetchSingle
    FetchSinglePayload,
    FetchSingleResponse,
    FetchSingleError,
    // Create
    CreatePayload,
    CreateResponse,
    CreateError,
    // Update
    UpdatePayload,
    UpdateResponse,
    UpdateError,
    // Delete
    DeletePayload,
    DeleteResponse,
    DeleteError
> {
    fetchList: FetchListState<FetchListPayload, FetchListResponse, FetchListError>;
    fetchSingle: FetchSingleState<FetchSinglePayload, FetchSingleResponse, FetchSingleError>;
    create: CreateState<CreatePayload, CreateResponse, CreateError>;
    update: UpdateState<UpdatePayload, UpdateResponse, UpdateError>;
    del: DeleteState<DeletePayload, DeleteResponse, DeleteError>;
}
```

I am looking for a way that will let me define all the generics once. For example:

```
interface CreateModelTypes<
    // FetchList
    FetchListPayload,
    FetchListResponse,
    FetchListError,
    // FetchSingle
    FetchSinglePayload,
    FetchSingleResponse,
    FetchSingleError,
    // Create
    CreatePayload,
    CreateResponse,
    CreateError,
    // Update
    UpdatePayload,
    UpdateResponse,
    UpdateError,
    // Delete
    DeletePayload,
    DeleteResponse,
    DeleteError
> {
    // FetchList
    FetchListPayload: FetchListPayload;
    FetchListResponse: FetchListResponse;
    FetchListError: FetchListError;
    // FetchSingle
    FetchSinglePayload: FetchSinglePayload;
    FetchSingleResponse: FetchSingleResponse;
    FetchSingleError: FetchSingleError;
    // Create
    CreatePayload: CreatePayload;
    CreateResponse: CreateResponse;
    CreateError: CreateError;
    // Update
    UpdatePayload: UpdatePayload;
    UpdateResponse: UpdateResponse;
    UpdateError: UpdateError;
    // Delete
    DeletePayload: DeletePayload;
    DeleteResponse: DeleteResponse;
    DeleteError: DeleteError;
}
```

And then I will be able to define `ModelState` in the following way:

```
export interface ModelState<CreateModelTypes> {
    fetchList: FetchListState<CreateModelTypes.FetchListPayload, CreateModelTypes.FetchListResponse, CreateModelTypes.FetchListError>;
    fetchSingle: FetchSingleState<CreateModelTypes.FetchSinglePayload, CreateModelTypes.FetchSingleResponse, CreateModelTypes.FetchSingleError>;
    create: CreateState<CreateModelTypes.CreatePayload, CreateModelTypes.CreateResponse, CreateModelTypes.CreateError>;
    update: UpdateState<CreateModelTypes.UpdatePayload, CreateModelTypes.UpdateResponse, CreateModelTypes.UpdateError>;
    del: DeleteState<CreateModelTypes.DeletePayload, CreateModelTypes.DeleteResponse, CreateModelTypes.DeleteError>;
}
```

Unfortunately this syntax is invalid. Is there something in typescript that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider making `CreateModelTypes` a concrete type with known keys but whose value types are all `unknown`:

```
type CreateModelTypes = Record<
  | "FetchListPayload" | "FetchListResponse" | "FetchListError"
  | "FetchSinglePayload"  | "FetchSingleResponse"  | "FetchSingleError"
  | "CreatePayload" | "CreateResponse" | "CreateError"
  | "UpdatePayload" | "UpdateResponse" | "UpdateError"
  | "DeletePayload" | "DeleteResponse"  | "DeleteError",
  unknown
>;
```

And then make `ModelState` generic in `C` which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `CreateModelTypes`. Note that in TypeScript, if you have an object type `T` with a key of type `K`, then the type of the property at that key is written `T[K]` (and not `T.K`).  It's called an "indexed access type" or a [lookup type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types).  So `ModelState` turns into this:

```
interface ModelState<C extends CreateModelTypes> {
  fetchList: FetchListState<
    C["FetchListPayload"], C["FetchListResponse"], C["FetchListError"]
  >;
  fetchSingle: FetchSingleState<
    C["FetchSinglePayload"], C["FetchSingleResponse"], C["FetchSingleError"]
  >;
  create: CreateState<
    C["CreatePayload"], C["CreateResponse"], C["CreateError"]
  >;
  update: UpdateState<
    C["UpdatePayload"], C["UpdateResponse"], C["UpdateError"]
  >;
  del: DeleteState<
    C["DeletePayload"], C["DeleteResponse"], C["DeleteError"]
  >;
}
```

and then you'd specify the generic type like this:

```
type SomeModelState = ModelState<{
  FetchListPayload: string;
  FetchListResponse: number;
  FetchListError: Error;
  FetchSinglePayload: number;
  FetchSingleResponse: boolean;
  FetchSingleError: Error;
  CreatePayload: boolean;
  CreateResponse: object;
  CreateError: Error;
  UpdatePayload: object;
  UpdateResponse: RegExp;
  UpdateError: Error;
  DeletePayload: RegExp;
  DeleteResponse: string;
  DeleteError: Error;
}>;
```

---

The apparent pattern in the names/types suggests that you should do the grouping two levels deep, as in:

```
interface State {
  Payload: unknown;
  Response: unknown;
  Error: unknown;
}

interface CreateModelTypes {
  FetchList: State;
  FetchSingle: State;
  Create: State;
  Update: State;
  Delete: State;
}

interface ModelState<C extends CreateModelTypes> {
  fetchList: FetchListState<
    C["FetchList"]["Payload"],
    C["FetchList"]["Response"],
    C["FetchList"]["Error"]
  >;
  fetchSingle: FetchSingleState<
    C["FetchSingle"]["Payload"],
    C["FetchSingle"]["Response"],
    C["FetchSingle"]["Error"]
  >;
  create: CreateState<
    C["Create"]["Payload"],
    C["Create"]["Response"],
    C["Create"]["Error"]
  >;
  update: UpdateState<
    C["Update"]["Payload"],
    C["Update"]["Response"],
    C["Update"]["Error"]
  >;
  del: DeleteState<
    C["Delete"]["Payload"],
    C["Delete"]["Response"],
    C["Delete"]["Error"]
  >;
}

type SomeModelState = ModelState<{
  FetchList: { Payload: string; Response: number; Error: Error };
  FetchSingle: { Payload: number; Response: boolean; Error: Error };
  Create: { Payload: boolean; Response: object; Error: Error };
  Update: { Payload: object; Response: RegExp; Error: Error };
  Delete: { Payload: RegExp; Response: string; Error: Error };
}>;
```

---

Either of those works.  I have to say that the IntelliSense inside the specification for `C` in `SomeModelState` is pretty bad (it doesn't hint the keys even though the compiler gets very angry if you leave one out) so I might open an issue about that... not sure.  (update: opened [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33302), we'll see if anyone bites)

---

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-eOOs-fsoe7LwPqSQtpefjXl+t7gQ+pifl+L7ge+7wIdKSGgbu8EHkMpBJpMfgqF6w7PhOXpwWh4Qvl6KHwfO0HUQRPBYQB0pAdKlYqLG1YTrGFHCC+sa0XOt6xix7GOMQXwjCgAKQG2VYzAsCnnF24TLtYD4qOwmgirhSAaewKEqMASZgAARhAmj6YZZC7gYPrWYi56nlpSCmRZVk2VkF7GUg5kAgCuAgMA3knr+9nJI5+mwba-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-GrHhBJpCcet9sQTwUH92zu819H-q3w3+8fof35PzPbfn6QCSC0XaUxknJCAHs-DKSBCcVSzldYqAUG5MaWANB+Q8pZay01YTFVhIMeBJdcCINUD1EyZlMFoM-kkRKwVQrYI6o5fB7JwLELcjQ5KlDIw0kqrleA+V6G4M0Ew6UXpWGkKQFlXh-D6r9Sai1AR9DhHhFjGI9evVRCyMGhorhSQUGYA0JFXcSi5rxGAUAA)